# Apache2 Error Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: apache2

I am trying to run an apache2 web server with linode and ubuntu. I got the following error

```
    Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.
```

After running

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

I ran the commands they offered and got:

```
systemctl status apache2.service

× apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-04-28 12:59:56 UTC; 2min 13s ago
   Duration: 27min 6.692s
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 6388 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 11ms
```

and

```
journalctl -xeu apache2.service
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
-- No entries --
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? If you need any other information ask I just didn't want to overflow the question

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

First, read your error messages. Does `id` show that you're in one of the groups `adm`, or `systemd-journal`? Contact your system administrator or `sudo adduser $USER systemd-journal`, followed by logout/login, as groups are set up by `login`.

Alternatively you could use `sudo`;

```
sudo journalctl -xeu apache2.service
```

Second, your `apache2` has been up for `Duration: 27min 6.692s`. Did you forget to `stop` the old `apache2`?

Third, is any other process listening on TCP Port 80? `sudo lsof  itcp:80`. Clean that up. Port listening can't be shared.

Read `man journalctl lsof sudo service`.

Comment: How do I get to the error massage